# Destructuring the left-hand-side of `Optional[s:v]`

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax

It is useful to be able to provide default values in pattern-matching, for example, if an element has a `key` but no corresponding `value`, you can take the `value` to be zero:

```
Cases[
 {
  {a, b, {key, value1}, c},
  {e, {key, value2}, e},
  {o, p, {key}, t},
  {e, f, g}
  },
 {key, value_ : 0} :> value,
 {2}
 ]
```

But I would like to go further, and say, if a key-value pair fails to materialize, give 0 anyway:

```
Cases[
 {
  {a, b, {key, value1}, c},
  {e, {key, value2}, e},
  {o, p, {key}, t},
  {e, f, g}
  },
 {key, value_ : 0} : 0 :> value,
 {2}
 ]
```

This is a syntax error in Mathematica (documentation below). It would be nice to have this power anyway, and it seems well-defined. Is there some trick that can be done to enable this?

Edit:
This is how the procedure of pattern-matching with optional values is carried out in my mental model. When the computer is given

```
ReplaceAll[
 {key},
 {key, value_ : 0} :> value
 ]
```

It looks foremost for pairs of the form {key,_}. If it finds such a pair, it replaces it with the value in the slot. If it does not find such a pair, then it looks instead for {key}. If it finds this, it replaces it with the default (`0`) of the pattern appearing in the slot.

```
ReplaceAll[
 {key},
 {key, value_ : 0} : (This doesn't matter) :> value
 ]
```

Then what I thought should happen for the above code is that, upon failing to match either {key, _} or {key}, the pattern should finally match any form of expression and place the default of `value` on the right. The term appearing on the right-hand-side of the outer `Optional` having no relevance as it isn't reference in the right-hand-side of the `RuleDelayed`.

Is it wrongheaded to expect this to be possible? I would like for it to be, because there is some complex destructuring that I would like to do in other scenarios that cannot otherwise be handled. For example, the destructured `Optional` may not be the outer-most piece of the `Pattern`.

[image]

Comment: So, what would your desired out put be?

Comment: `{value1, value2, 0,0}`

Comment: Can you explain why? I'm confused. Which element corresponds to that second 0?

Comment: Oh, are you wanting to guarantee a result for each item at level 1? You should probably do something with `Map` if so.

Comment: I see what you mean... It isn't assigned on the right-hand-side of the rule

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using functional constructs altogether to get better at rule programming

Comment: Well, I hate to say it, but yes, I think your expectation is wrongheaded. When patterns are matching, we need to bind things. To say that the default for the larger expression doesn't matter doesn't make sense to me, because for the rule to work we'd need to bind something to `value`, but by definition, there's nothing for it to bind to if we're in the larger default case.

Comment: Or to put it another way, you're trying to create a sort of fall-through default at the top level, but it doesn't make sense to use `Optional` at that level, because you've got nothing to match against at that point. You're falling through through to empty space.

Answer (score 4):

*Edited because I didn't realize that `key` was intended to be literal.*

```
test = {{a, b, {key, value1}, c}, {e, {key, value2}, e}, {o, p, {key}, t}, {e, f, g}};

FirstCase[#, {key, val_} :> val, 0] & /@ test
(* {value1, value2, 0, 0} *)
```

I used `FirstCase` because I wasn't sure if there was a guarantee that there would be at most one match per item (and maybe I shouldn't have assumed that you wanted one result per item anyway). And also, `FirstCase` allows you to specify a default.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I can clarify better; my question isn't really about `Cases` but about patterns. I will make a better effort to specify my question; sorry I wasn't thinking clearly enough before.

Answer (score 3):

*Edited because I didn't realize that `key` was intended to be literal.*

Okay, how about pattern matching at a higher level?

```
Cases[test, {___, a : {key, _} : {Null, 0}, ___} :> a[[2]]]
```

Comment: This is definitely interesting, thank you. There is a tradeoff, however, in that we have given up on referring to the optional value by name and instead refer to it by its place in a larger expression, whose name is immaterial. In this sense we haven't benefited from destructuring.

Comment: Okay. I think it's the semantics of `Cases` that's making this confusing. It's hard to imagine the need for a default for `Cases`, because then you'd expect a result for every non-match, and what does that mean? You got two matches at level 2; how can we expect `Cases` to know that you want exactly four results? It's not looking at level 2 in a hierarchical way, it's just literally looking at level 2 as its own thing.

Comment: I will add an example without `Cases`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your new example:

```
ReplaceAll[{key}, {key, value_ : 0} : "blah" :> value]
```

This is just a syntax error, because of how `:` is used as a special form. The `:` is problematic, because it can denote either `Optional` or just `Pattern`. In this case, it can't be resolved to a valid pattern or a valid optional. So, we need to be explicit:

```
ReplaceAll[{key}, Optional[{key, value_ : 0}, "blah"] :> value]
```

This can now be parsed, but if you read the resulting error message, you'll see the problem:

> Optional pattern Optional[{key,value_:0},blah] has no enclosing pattern so no optional value can be matched.

There's no higher level pattern in which this bit is optional. `Optional` is supposed to be part of a larger pattern. Your expectation is something like "if you match anything else, then use this outer default", but the pattern doesn't "match anything else", it just fails to match, and in failing to match, there's no sub-part to assign the default value to.

Comment: If you're interested, I've figured it out. I am writing my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, although not very elegant, is to use `Alternatives` and manipulate the assignment that shows up in the rule. The way this works is that it replaces all the pattern variables which show up in the assignment with `wrapper[{default value,variable}]`. Then it does the pattern match. If the `variable` is not bound, we get `wrapper[{default value}]`. Finally, it takes the last element of the list appearing within `wrapper`: the default value if no variable were bound, and the pattern-matched value otherwise. The pattern-match to nothing is done with `Alternatives` and a blank pattern.

```
AscertainDefaults[pattern_] :=
 Cases[
  pattern,
  k_Optional :> Thread[{k[[2]], k[[1]][[1]]}], All
  ]

SetDefaultsReplaceAll[
  expr_, pattern_, assignment_
  ] :=
 Block[
  {ammendedAssignment, wrapper, result},
  ammendedAssignment = assignment /. Table[
     Last[default] -> wrapper[default],
     {default, AscertainDefaults[pattern]}
     ];
  result = expr /. pattern -> ammendedAssignment;
  result /. wrapper[{x___}] :> Last[{x}]
  ]

test = {{a, b, {key, value1}, c}, {e, {key, value2}, e}, {o, p, {key},
     t}, {e, f, g}};
pattern = {({key, value_ : 0} | {key} | _) ...};
assignment = value;
```

With this in place, we get the desired behavior using

```
SetDefaultsReplaceAll[
   #,
   pattern,
   assignment
   ] & /@ test
```

where the map was as necessary as the level specification of `Cases` in the original.

The annoying aspect is that the evaluator makes one fight to grab the names of the variables appearing in the pattern, so I haven't figured out how to do this where the Rule appears as a Rule, instead of a pattern and assignment separately.

A more difficult case: this one places all the quantities of apples, bananas, and pears in order for each collection appearing in the data. If a collection does not contain one of the types of quantities, then it replaces it with the default value 0.

```
data = {{{13, pears}, {4, apples}, {8, bananas}}, {{2, bananas}, {4, 
     apples}, {19, pears}}, {{5, pears}}, {{10, pears}, {6, 
     bananas}, {2, apples}}, {{19, pears}}, {{8, pears}, {6, 
     apples}}, {{7, bananas}}};
pattern = {({a_ : 0, apples} | {b_ : 0, bananas} | {p_ : 0, pears}) ...};
assignment = {a, b, p};
SetDefaultsReplaceAll[
 data,
 pattern,
 assignment
 ]
```

Output:

```
{{4,8,13},{4,2,19},{0,0,5},{2,6,10},{0,0,19},{6,0,8},{0,7,0}}
```